# Optimal Control of Nonlinear System with Constrained Input and Free End Time

Tags: boundary-value-problem, optimal-control

Thanks to Dimitry, I have edited the question to correct some errors.

I have been working on the optimal control of an underwater vehicle attempting to dock onto a charging station. Limiting the problem to three degrees of freedom, the nonlinear dynamic equations can be expressed as

$\mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)),$

where $\mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix} Q & \delta_\mathrm{s} \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x & z & \theta & u & w & q & n & u_\mathrm{p} \end{bmatrix}^T$.

In order to dock, the state vector should have the following initial and end conditions

$\mathbf{x}_0=\begin{bmatrix} x_0 & z_0 & \theta_0 & u_0 & w_0 & q_0 & n_0 & u_{\mathrm{p},0} \end{bmatrix}^T,$

$\mathbf{x}_\mathrm{f}=\begin{bmatrix} x_\mathrm{f} & z_\mathrm{f} & \theta_\mathrm{f} & u_\mathrm{f} & w_\mathrm{f} & q_\mathrm{f} & \mathrm{free} & \mathrm{free} \end{bmatrix}^T.$

Note that the last two states are free at the end time $t_\mathrm{f}$ and I am not sure if this will cause issues.

Taking into account that high values of the control input are undesirable, I have come up with the following cost-function for the constrained optimisation problem (due to physical limits):

$J = 0.5 \int_0^{t_\mathrm{f}} \sum_{j=1}^2 w_{u,j} \left[u_j(t) \right]^2 \mathrm{d}t $ subject to

$\mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)),$

$\mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0,$

$\mathbf{x}(t_\mathrm{f}) = \mathbf{x}_\mathrm{f},$

$\mathbf{u}_\mathrm{min} \leq \mathbf{u}(t) \leq \mathbf{u}_\mathrm{max}.$

Note that at the moment, I am considering a fixed end time.

Using an indirect method, the costate equations may be found as follows.

Based on my cost function, the Hamiltonian is

$H(t) = -0.5\left( w_{u,1}Q^2(t) + w_{u,2}\delta_\mathrm{s}^2(t) \right) + \mathbf{p}^T(t) \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}(t),\mathbf{u}(t)),$

so that I get the following equations for the state and costate

$\mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = \frac{\partial H(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{p},t)}{\partial \mathbf{p}} ,$

$\mathbf{\dot{p}}(t) = -\frac{\partial H(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{p},t)}{\partial \mathbf{x}} ,$

with the stationary condition

$\frac{\partial H(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{p},t)}{\partial \mathbf{u}} = 0.$

Furthermore, the boundary and transversality conditions can be expressed as

$\mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0, $

$p_n (t_\mathrm{f}) = 0,$

$p_{u_\mathrm{p}} (t_\mathrm{f}) = 0.$

My **first question** is how I can convert this into a boundary value problem so that I can use a tool like `bvp4c` in MATLAB to solve it. In particular, I know that the state equations should be solved forward in time and the costate backwards in time, but am not sure how to do that with `bvp4c`. My other problem is that I feel that I am not using the values of $\mathbf{x}_\mathrm{f}$ with fixed values. As a result, the number of boundary conditions is less than the number of ordinary differential equations, which is a problem.

Then, I have problems converting the problem into a free end time problem. I have seen that the procedure for this involves rescaling the time to $\tau=\frac{t}{t_\mathrm{f}}$, with $\tau \in [0,1]$. As a result, the optimal control problem is modified to

$J  = 0.5 \int_0^{t_\mathrm{f}} \left\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^2 w_{u,j} \left[u_j(t) \right]^2 + 2 \right\rbrace \mathrm{d}t $ subject to

$\mathbf{\dot{x}}_\mathrm{new}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) \\ \dot{t} \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} t_\mathrm{f} \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}(\tau),\mathbf{u}(\tau)) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$

$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}(0) \\ t(0) \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_0 \\ t_\mathrm{f} \end{bmatrix},$

$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}(1) \\ t(1)  \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_\mathrm{f} \\ t_\mathrm{f} \end{bmatrix},$

$\mathbf{u}_\mathrm{min} \leq \mathbf{u}(\tau) \leq \mathbf{u}_\mathrm{max},$

$0<\tau<1.$

The new Hamiltonian then becomes

$H(t) = - 1 - 0.5\left( w_{u,1}Q^2(\tau) + w_{u,2}\delta_\mathrm{s}^2(\tau) \right) + \mathbf{p}^T(\tau) t_\mathrm{f} \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}(\tau),\mathbf{u}(\tau))$ and the stationarity conditions

$\mathbf{\dot{p}}(\tau) = -t_\mathrm{f} \frac{\partial H(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},\mathbf{p},\tau)}{\partial \mathbf{x}},$

including the additional costate for the time.

My **second question** is whether this procedure for free end time is now expressed error-free. Additionally, as in the first question, how can I express this as a boundary value problem I can solved with `bvp4c`?

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what was the reason to add a terminal cost, i.e., $w_i(x(t_f)-x_f)^2$ if you fix $x_f$?

Comment: if you minimize (I guess so), there should be a minus in front of the first term in the Hamiltonian $H$. Next, the only transversality conditions are that the adjoin variables corresponding to free (at $t=t_f$) variables must be $= 0$ at $t_f$

Comment: Your approach to rescaling is valid, but you didn't get it correct. If you introduce a new state valiable ($t$), then there should be a new adjoin variable, say $p_t$. So, you keep old $p$'s, but add a new one.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I will have a go at it to try to update the set of equations.

Comment: Do you think that I can get rid of the cost on the final position, if I include the constraint? Thank you for that: I had not thought about it. The reason why I had that cost function to start with was because I first tried with the direct method, but could not get it to converge (my initial guess must have been too far off).

Comment: You shouldn't mix up numerical and analytical approaches. When dealing with Pontryagin's MP there are two options: either you fix $x_f$ or you impose a terminal cost by adding a sort of $k(x(t_f)-x_f)^2$ to the cost function. The latter condition means that you do not require $x$ to be *exactly* equal to $x_f$ but rather as close as possible to it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now rewritten the problem as you recommended. However, I am still missing the last bits before I can solve it numerically, namely I feel I now have 6 too few boundary equations.

Comment: A Model Predictive Control approach seems to be quite well suited for the stated problem.